# strptime not formatting my date correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I was wondering if anyone smarter than me can see what i'm doing wrong.

I'm mapping date formats using regex, and I want to convert my dates to `"%Y-%m-%d"`

When testing with `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`, my dates don't convert correctly. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I have no idea how to deal with the unconverted data remaining.

Here is the test code for your reference.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
import pandas as pd


def conv_date(dte: str) -> datetime: #actul is datetime
    acceptable_mappings = {
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",

    }
    for regex in acceptable_mappings.keys():
        if re.match(regex, dte):
            return datetime.strptime(dte, acceptable_mappings[regex])
    raise Exception(f"Expected date in one of supported formats, got {dte}")


def full_list_parse(unclean_list: list) -> list:
    return [conv_date(dte) for dte in unclean_list]


mock_dict = [
    {"name": "xx", "role": "loves only-fans", "date": "2023-07-26 12:46:21"},
    {"name": "dz", "role": "legend", "date": "2023-07-26"},

]

df = pd.DataFrame(mock_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(df)
    df['date_clean'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: conv_date(x))
    print(df)
```

my results:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  12:46:21
  name             role                 date
0   xx  loves only-fans  2023-07-26 12:46:21
1   dz           legend           2023-07-26
```

my desired results:

```
  name             role                 date
0   xx  loves only-fans           2023-07-26
1   dz           legend           2023-07-26
```

Comment: [`.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches only at the start of the whole string. What you want is [`.fullmatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch). Also, escaping `:` is unnecessary, and you can just use `.apply(conv_date)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first try `pd.to_datetime`:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='mixed', dayfirst=False)

df['only_date'] = df['date'].dt.date
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  name             role                date   only_date
0   xx  loves only-fans 2023-07-26 12:46:21  2023-07-26
1   dz           legend 2023-07-26 00:00:00  2023-07-26
```

Comment: Can you show me how you did that as im getting an error

Comment: @MizanurChoudhury What error are you getting? The key is to use the parameters `format='mixed', dayfirst=False` in `pd_todatetime()`

Comment: sorry i didn't understand, but now i understand. it was to replace the contents of if name _main_