# Converting multiple dates, using regex and strptime and applying results using lamda apply

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dataframe, lambda

I'm mapping date formats using regex, and I want to convert my dates to `"%Y-%m-%d"`

When testing with `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`, my dates don't convert correctly. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I have no idea how to deal with the unconverted data remaining.

Here is the test code for your reference.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
import pandas as pd


def conv_date(dte: str) -> datetime: #actul is datetime
    acceptable_mappings = {
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}": "%d-%m-%Y",
        "\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}": "%Y/%m/%d",
        "\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}": "%d/%m/%Y",
        "\d{8}": '%d%m%Y',
        "\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}": '%d %m %Y',
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",

    }
    for regex in acceptable_mappings.keys():
        if re.match(regex, dte):
            return datetime.strptime(dte, acceptable_mappings[regex])
    raise Exception(f"Expected date in one of supported formats, got {dte}")


def full_list_parse(unclean_list: list) -> list:
    return [conv_date(dte) for dte in unclean_list]


mock_dict = [
    {"name": "dz", "role": "legend", "date": "2023-07-26"},
    {"name": "mc", "role": "sounds like a dj", "date": "26-07-2023"},
    {"name": "xc", "role": "loves xcom", "date": "2023/07/26"},
    {"name": "lz", "role": "likes a to fly", "date": "26/07/2023"},
    {"name": "wc", "role": "has a small bladder", "date": "26072023"},
    {"name": "aa", "role": "warrior of the crystal", "date": "26 07 2023"},
    {"name": "xx", "role": "loves only-fans", "date": "2023-07-26 12:46:21"},

]

df = pd.DataFrame(mock_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(df)
    df['date_clean'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: conv_date(x))
    print(df)
```

my results:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  12:46:21
  name                    role                 date
0   dz                  legend           2023-07-26
1   mc        sounds like a dj           26-07-2023
2   xc              loves xcom           2023/07/26
3   lz          likes a to fly           26/07/2023
4   wc     has a small bladder             26072023
5   aa  warrior of the crystal           26 07 2023
6   xx         loves only-fans  2023-07-26 12:46:21
```

my desired results:

```
  name                    role        date          date_clean
0   dz                  legend  2023-07-26          2023-07-26
1   mc        sounds like a dj  26-07-2023          2023-07-26
2   xc              loves xcom  2023/07/26          2023-07-26
3   lz          likes a to fly  26/07/2023          2023-07-26
4   wc     has a small bladder    26072023          2023-07-26
5   aa  warrior of the crystal  26 07 2023          2023-07-26
6   xx         loves only-fans  2023-07-26 12:46:21 2023-07-26
```

Comment: See [this comment of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76789581#comment135376398_76789581) in your previous question.

Comment: Quick question about this. When using fullmatch all my results are turned into a 2023-07-26 00:00:00 where as im looking for a 2023-07-26  format.

Comment: That's because you are returning a `datetime` object, which has the "time" part. Use `.strptime().date()` to get only the date.

Comment: Amazing! Quick question. How come i cant add the .date() on my return. How come i have to add it when its assigned as a variable?

`converted_date = datetime.strptime(dte, acceptable_mappings[regex]).date()`

Comment: That shouldn't be the case with the code you provided in this question. Ask a new question with all the details please.

Comment: ignore me! It was my ide throwing up an error, as i hadn't changed my code to -> date, def conv_date(dte: str) -> date:

Thanks for your help!